# Upload files to s3 AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider ios

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to upload file to s3 and I always got next error message

> 2015-08-05 14:35:53.931 BellyBuds[47981:2189296] Upload failed: [Error
>   Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t
>   be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain error 0.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7fd40a40d8f0
>   {HostId=wo/bHFvnQjGuiLic3IhL+jicVfeIcuR6M4HXz/nB9WRt/T09h16bbR77nkqKngzj,
>   Bucket=bbbname, Endpoint=bbstagemusic.s3.amazonaws.com,
>   Message=The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed
>   using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this
>   endpoint., Code=PermanentRedirect, RequestId=6D250A718C640210}]

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                             identityId:[params valueForKey:@"IdentityId"]
                                                                                         identityPoolId:[params valueForKey:@"IdentityPoolId"]
                                                                                                 logins:@{@"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com": params[@"Token"]}];

//credProvider.logins = @{ @(AWSCognitoLoginProviderKeyLoginWithAmazon): params[@"Token"] };
AWSServiceConfiguration *serviceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credProvider];

AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
uploadRequest.body = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[BBFileManager getRecordingList][0]];
uploadRequest.key = [[BBFileManager getRecordingList][0] lastPathComponent];
uploadRequest.bucket = @"bbbucket";

AWSServiceManager *serv =   [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager];
serv.defaultServiceConfiguration = serviceConfiguration;

[AWSS3TransferManager registerS3TransferManagerWithConfiguration:serviceConfiguration forKey:@"transferKey"];
[[[AWSS3TransferManager S3TransferManagerForKey:@"transferKey"] upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id (AWSTask *task) {


     return nil;
 }];
```

I use correct data and set right region. I try use other regions and make other stuff, but this not be helpful. I always got errors related to regions and endpoint. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem! 
uploadRequest.key = [[BBFileManager getRecordingList][0] lastPathComponent];
property uploadRequest.key should contain future file path for example, if future file will be located at /bbucketname/music/IdentityId/file.mp3,  value of the key should be music/IdentityId/file.mp3